# resolve and $q.reject not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to block user from going to some route if he doesnt have payment method. this is the code:

```
      resolve: {
          hasPayment: ['userService', 'paymentsService','$q', function( userService,paymentsService, $q ) {
             if(userService.oAuth) {
                 paymentsService.getPayments().then(function(res) {
                     if(res.data.data.length) return $q.reject({hasPayment:true});
                  });
                }
              }]
            }

 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState,toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            console.log(error);  
  });
```

but its not get the error if the condition true, why?

Comment: Don't you want to reject when length == 0 instead? Also, you're not returning the promise. So the function always returned undefined. It should be `return paymentsService.getPayments()...`.

Comment: No thats for route that he add payment method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a promise that will be rejected, using $q.reject you just create a new deferred and rejects it but the "resolve" won't wait for this response because it's not aware of it.

The best thing to do would be to reject the promise directly in paymentsService.getPayments(),
then your code would look like this:

```
  resolve: {
      hasPayment: ['userService', 'paymentsService','$q', function( userService,paymentsService, $q ) {
             return paymentsService.getPayments();
          }]
        }
```

If you can't do it for some reason, just create a new promise and reject it, some like this:

```
  resolve: {
      hasPayment: ['userService', 'paymentsService','$q', function( userService,paymentsService, $q ) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();

         if(userService.oAuth) {
             paymentsService.getPayments().then(function(res) {
                 if(res.data.data.length) {
                    deferred.reject({hasPayment:false});
                 } else {
                    deferred.resolve();
                 }
              });
         } else {
            deferred.resolve();
         }

         return deferred.promise;
       }]
   }
```

Comment: @Asaf David and anguLaravel, see my answer below for an improvement to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on Asaf David's solution, but need a code block to demonstrate, so posting as an answer (if there's a better mechanism, please let me know)

Since a promise's final result is the result of the *chain of promises returned*, you can simply chain `.then()` and return the appropriate value from inside.  Asaf's answer can be written much simpler without using the "deferred anti-pattern" (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns):

```
  resolve: {
      hasPayment: ['userService', 'paymentsService','$q', function( userService,paymentsService, $q ) {
         if(userService.oAuth) {
             return paymentsService.getPayments().then(function(res) {
                 if (res.data.data.length)
                   return $q.reject({hasPayment: false}); // hasPayment is rejected.
                 // since you seem to be using hasPayment as a pass/fail you could even 
                 // get by without returning anything here, but return true to be explicit.
                 return true;
             }
         }
       }]
   }
```

Comment: That's true but you forgot to handle the else case of userService.oAuth